# Asymptotic of a sum

Tags: asymptotics

How do I find asymptotic of $\sum_{i=1}^n i^k$.

All I noticed is it is summation of inverse harmonic number.

Comment: For finite $n$, this sum can be written [as a polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula).

Comment: Use the Euler-Maclaurin Summation Formula.